# Multiscreen by DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, displayport

I have a Dell unit connected to two screen by Display Port. After first reboot, only one screen is working. The other displays "no DP signal". If I change the cable from one port to another I note that only one port is working.

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: If only one port is working that sounds like a hardware problem. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I have the 20.04 version. Moreover if I initialize the computer in factory version it will work until I reboot the system the first time. The computer is new.